# How to get records with specific IDs?

Tags: swift, cloudkit

I can easily get record with specific ID. If I need something specific then I can use CKQueryOperation.

I need to provide it with proper predicate, but I can't specify IDs as parameter of predicate, because it doesn't support CKRecordValue protocol. Another idea is to use CKReference, but how to write proper predicate then?

If I try to use array of Strings and evaluate agains recordID.recordName key path:

```
    var references:[String] = IDs.map{$0.recordName}
    var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY recordID.recordName IN %@", references)
```

I get following error:

```
<CKError 0x17005f3b0: "Invalid Arguments" (12/1009); "Invalid predicate: recordKey (recordID.recordName) contains invalid characters">
```

Predicate format output:

```
predicate ANY recordID.recordName IN {"AFF487BE-4A7E-4F76-8185-79FA2E1EFC33", "D4D83B37-97DE-4BF2-9E43-4C5522E36DF1", "0126008A-0B42-4F95-AB31-BB13B6215475", "6DE83AD9-F307-467D-A5EF-AD2B97B8E7F7", "F701ADBF-9BE7-4F42-8CA9-44D2D0E629F8", "38C4FB60-8A65-43F9-8E1E-4C48D5B60DCD"}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi, @Alex do you know how to get the UDID string from CKRecordID? e.g. "AFF487BE-4A7E-4F76-8185-79FA2E1EFC33"

Comment: Hi, @codingrhythm. You can use recordName property of CKRecordID for that.

Comment: you are right, just realised now, what a stupid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `CKFetchRecordsOperation` to fetch records whose RecordIDs you already know:

```
let fetchRecordsOperation = CKFetchRecordsOperation(recordIDs: recordIDs)
fetchRecordsOperation.desiredKeys = desiredKeys
```

Init the operation with an array of the CKRecordIDs you'd like to retrieve and it will return each individual record result in the `perRecordCompletionBlock` and all records fetched in `fetchRecordsCompletionBlock`.

You can retrieve the complete records by default or just a subset of their values by setting an array of NSStrings to the `desiredKeys` property with the names of the fields you'd like to retrieve.

Comment: Please show us an complete example fetching and querying records with specific IDs. Thank you!